# Convert string to function

Tags: html, forms, grails, groovy

On the view, I have hidden field:

`<g:hiddenField name="pageName" value="savePage1"/>`

then on controller (when form submitted) I have

`params.pageName = savePage1`

I also have function `savePage1()`

I tried to transform string to function but it doesn't work:

```
params.pageName + "()"
```

How can I call that function with given `params.pageName`?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you are just concatenating a string, not calling a method.  Instead, what you want is [dynamic method invocation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+Groovy).  Assuming your `savePage` method is in `this`:

```
String pageName = params.pageName
this."$pageName"()
```

The catch here is it seems like you are trusting user input, so you should make sure that `pageName` is in an approved whitelist, or you leave yourself exposed to some major vulnerabilities:

```
String pageName = params.pageName

if (!pageName in [ 'savePage1', 'savePage2' /* ... */]) {
    throw SomeException('Invalid pageName')
}

this."$pageName"()
```

Although I believe it's a little less performant, you could probably call [`Eval.me`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Eval.html) instead too, though the above approach is preferred.

Comment: well, first thanks for advance, I never thought about that way. I help me so much. Thanks you again.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is to create map of all callback functions like :

```
private def callbacks = [ 'savePage1' : { your();code();here(); },
                  'savePage2'  :{ some();other();code();here(); ]
```

And than call these functions like :

```
if(callbacks[params.pageName]){ 
   callbacks[params.pageName]()
}
```

Beauty of groovy - using closures. If you have savePage1 and savePage2 defined as method, above map would look like

```
private def callbacks = ['savePage1' : this.&savePage1, 'savePage2' : this.&savePage2 ]
```

and than, again call it same way

```
if(callbacks[params.pageName]){ 
   callbacks[params.pageName]()
}
```